# How can I write this code without if and elif statements?

Tags: python

I want to make my code more sophisticated, how can I do this?

```
if "valorant" in command:
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe"])

elif "comp" in command:
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")

elif "steam" in command:
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","steam.exe"])

elif "discord" in command:
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Discord.exe"])

elif "cyberpunk" in command:
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Cyberpunk2077.exe"])
```

Comment: What's about implementing **switch case** using a dictionary?

Comment: What is `command` that you are looking for substrings rather than an exact match?

Comment: @AziMez actually, Python currently supports `match` statements, which are a betteer way to make switch cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the commands to execute along with the keywords in a dictionary.

```py
commands = {
    "valorant": lambda: subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe"]),
    "comp": lambda: os.system("shutdown /s /t 1"),
    "stream": lambda: subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","steam.exe"]),
    "discord": lambda: subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Discord.exe"]),
    "cyberpunk": lambda: subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Cyberpunk2077.exe"])
}
for k, f in commands.items():
    if k in command:
        f()
        break
```

Comment: I can see an if statement :D

Comment: @Christian But no `elif`!

Comment: Just make it a try except lol to remove the if -> `try: ... ; except KeyError: ... ;`

Answer (score 2):

As @jthulhu mentioned in comment 3 of question, Python 3.10+ supports "switch" statements. I'm a fan so would like to toss it into the mix.

```py
def match_example(command):
    match command:
        case 'valorant':
            kill_valorant();
        case 'comp':
            shutdown_computer()
        case 'steam':
            kill_steam()
        case 'discord':
            kill_discord()
        case 'cyberpunk':
            kill_cyberpunk()
        case _:
            kill_everything_in_sight()
```

If command is a list of tokens, say for example `['kill', 'something'] you can use destructuring...

```py
def match_example(command):
    match command:
        case ['kill', 'valorant']:
            kill_valorant();
        case ['kill', 'comp']:
            shutdown_computer()
        case ['kill', 'steam']:
            kill_steam()
        case ['kill', 'discord']:
            kill_discord()
        case ['kill', 'cyberpunk']:
            kill_cyberpunk()
        case ['kill', _]:
            kill_everything_in_sight()
```

If your use of `in` is truly a string search that would require an advanced usage of `match` which is not at my fingertips.

...later...

Here is an example of match/case with `in string` conditions...

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InString(str):
    string: str

    def __eq__(self, item):
        return item in self.string

def advanced_match_example(command):
    match InString(command):
        case 'valorant':
            kill_valorant();
        case 'comp':
            shutdown_computer()
        case 'steam':
            kill_steam()
        case 'discord':
            kill_discord()
        case 'cyberpunk':
            kill_cyberpunk()
        case _:
            kill_everything_in_sight()
```

Comment: I should give credit where credit is due. The advanced use of match was derived from examples in [a Medium article](https://python.plainenglish.io/recipes-and-tricks-for-effective-structural-pattern-matching-in-python-852ddf498fa2) by a [Martin Heinz](https://medium.com/@martin.heinz)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import subprocess

def kill_valorant():
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe"])

def shutdown_computer():
    subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s", "/t", "1"])

def kill_steam():
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","steam.exe"])

def kill_discord():
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Discord.exe"])

def kill_cyberpunk():
    subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Cyberpunk2077.exe"])

commands = {
    "valorant": kill_valorant,
    "comp": shutdown_computer,
    "steam": kill_steam,
    "discord": kill_discord,
    "cyberpunk": kill_cyberpunk
}

def execute_command(command):
    # Get the function associated with the command and call it
    func = commands.get(command, lambda: "Invalid command")
    func()
```

Comment: This stores the functions in a dictionary with the commands as keys. The execute_command function takes a command as an argument and retrieves the corresponding function from the dictionary using the get method. The function is then called to execute the command.